# How do I set a date format to be YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, timestamp, datetime-format

I want to change the date format in PostgreSQL to be 
like this:

```
2019-03-21T00:00:00.
```

When I try

```
to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
```

I got this:

```
07/04/19 00:00
```

Also, if I change the format to be `YYYY-MM-DD''T''HH24:MI:SS`, e.g. to put two single quotes in each side of "T"

I get

```
2019-04-07'T'00:00:00
```

Thanks

Comment: it works fine with me, check the online demo also it works fine https://rextester.com/VXV82741

Comment: `to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')` will work as you expect assuming that `timestamp` is indeed a timestamp column.

Comment: @YCF_L I believe you have put *double* quotes around the `T` (which works), while the asker had tried *two single* quotes on either side (and reported that it didn’t work as desired). Thanks for showing a working solution.

Comment: Oh @Ole V.V. I didn't notice this ☺